# How to post message from Typescript to C#?

Tags: c#, typescript, postmessage

What is the correct way to post message from Typescript to C#? I am trying to receive message in C# with WebView_WebMessageReceived with the following code:

```
private void WebView_WebMessageReceived(object sender, CoreWebView2WebMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            var json = e.TryGetWebMessageAsString();
        }
```

I have tried the following in typescript file:

```
window.chrome.webview.postMessage("test");   
window.postMessage("test", '*');
window.postMessage({type: 'hello', payload: {}}, '*');
```

But the message is not being received in C#. The above code works in plain html instead of typescript. Suggestions please..

Comment: What do you mean by post message to C#? You mean calling an API or what?

Comment: @MohamadMousheimish I am using WebView2 in Windows Form C# to load a html (typescript included). There is WebMessageReceived event in WebView2 which should receive message when message is posted from html as included in this link: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2021/Jan/26/Chromium-WebView2-Control-and-NET-to-JavaScript-Interop-Part-2. All works good in plain html with JavaScript: window.chrome.webview.postMessage('Hello .NET from JavaScript'); but same thing doesn't work with typescript.

Answer (score 0):

*The title and description are a bit confusing. I'll suppose you are trying to call the `window.chrome.webview.postMessage` method from a TypeScript file and are getting an error from TypeScript.*

If you want to call the `window.chrome.webview.postMessage` method from a TypeScript file, you have to extend the Window type definition.

I did by creating a `global.d.ts` file in my project with that content:

```
export {};

declare global {
  interface Window {
    chrome: {
      webview: {
        postMessage: (message: any) => void;
      };
    };
  }
}
```